# React Child Component not re-rendering mapped state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

I have a form set up like follows
[image: Form visual]

There may be any number of categories, which are dynamically created in the parent component as follows

```
            <div>
                {
                    categories.map((category) => {
                        return (
                            <ProjectCategoryForm
                                category={ category.name }
                                key={ category.name }
                                handleChange={ handleDescriptions }
                                />
                        );
                    })
                }
            </div>
```

This child component handles the state of each individual category, wherein multiple product descriptions can be entered.

```
const ProjectCategoryForm = (props) => {
const [descriptions, setDescriptions] = useState([]);

return (
    <div>
        <div className="form-row justify-content-start">
            <h3>{ props.category }</h3>
        </div>
        <div className="form-row">
            { 
                descriptions.map((description) => {
                    return (
                        <p>{ description }</p>
                    );
                })
            }
        </div>
        <Formik
            initialValues={{
                description: "",
            }}
            onSubmit={ (values, {resetForm}) => {
                var newDescriptions = descriptions;
                newDescriptions.push(values.description);
                console.log(newDescriptions);
                props.handleChange(props.category, newDescriptions);
                setDescriptions(newDescriptions);
                resetForm();
            }}
            ...
```

As you can see, each category has a form which handles adding a new "description". The console log confirms that new descriptions are being created properly, however the child component is never rerendering to update that fact and actually show the descriptions from descriptions.map

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var newDescriptions = descriptions;
newDescriptions.push(values.description);
```

You are mutating the existing array rather than creating a new one. So when you call `setDescriptions(newDescriptions)`, react compares the old state and new state with a `===`, sees that they're the same array, and so skips rendering.

Instead, create a new array:

```
const newDescriptions = [...descriptions, values.description];
```

Comment: Seems I'd forgotten the basics with either using concat() or spread operator to update state arrays as you pointed out. I've accepted this answer.